# How to count the number of rows by variable in R

Tags: r

[image: dataframe]

Context: I am trying to determine a way to create an extra step in between my dataset and the code below or optimise the code altogether. Currently, the data frame "df_b" looks as follows. In column 4, the repetitions exceed 1 (as they denote the number of times a word appears +/- 5 words of a term.

Problem: I am trying to count the number of lemmas that appear within each year and create a tibble. This is what I have tried to do below but I realise now that I am not doing so as some rows in `repetition` exceed 1.

Possible solution 1: create another column for each rows holding the value 1, then input into code below
Possible solution 2: create new tibble by grouping by year and counting the number of lemmas in each year (not sure how to code this one up)

```
# sum the repetitions of words by year
sum_repeat_b <- aggregate(df_b[, 4], list(df_b$year), sum)
sum_repeat_b <- dplyr::rename(sum_repeat_b, "year"="Group.1")
sum_repeat_b <- dplyr::rename(sum_repeat_b, "sum_repeat_b"="x")

show(sum_repeat_b)
```

Comment: Can you please post the data with ```dput()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work for you? The following code should count the number of unique values in the `lemma` column within each group based on the `year` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(count = n_distinct(lemma))
```

Comment: Thank you Ox--that is exactly what I needed! I clearly need to learn to use dplyr and tidyr package. In this example, what is tidyr used for?